# How can I get html from React app website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

So, the problem is that I want to get data from node.js website with jQuery from another website, but when I do that, I only get `<script>` in `<div id="root">`, but when I visit the React website, there are `<div>`s inside `<div id="root">`.

Could someone help me?

React website: [https://kindle.vercel.app/\](https://kindle.vercel.app/%5C)
React code: https://github.com/MrGlebTiK/GG

Html website (in which website I will get node.js data): [https://kindlehtml.netlify.app/\](https://kindlehtml.netlify.app/%5C)
Html website code: https://github.com/MrGlebTiK/htmlkindle

Edit: what I am trying to do is see if browser that does not load my node.js website will load data from just front-end website.

Comment: you need to render it in a headless browser like puppeteer

Comment: Albeit your goal seems unclear to me, a way to achieve composability with abstraction of the frontend framework is using web components. You can package your ReactJS app with Direflow, import the produced JS script and simply add the defined tag.